# How to increase space between menu and social media icon a little

Tags: html, css

How do I increase the space between my menu bar and the social media icon a little? Note that I don't want to float left and right, it does not give me the desired result.

This is my nav bar code.

```
<nav>
    <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Service +</label>
            <a href="#">Service</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Methodology</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
            <a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Web Design +</label>
            <a href="#">Web Design</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li>
                    <!-- Second Tier Drop Down -->        
                    <label for="drop-3" class="toggle">Tutorials +</label>
                    <a href="#">Tutorials</a>         
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-3"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
            <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Courses +</label>
            <a href="#">Courses</a>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Agriculture</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/soc/facebook.png" height="32" width="15"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/soc/twitter.png" height="32" width="32"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/soc/instagram.png" height="32" width="34"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the code for the styling sheet:

```
/* Styling for navbar menu */

/* CSS Document */

.toggle,
[id^=drop] {
    display: none;
}

/* Giving a background-color to the nav container. */
nav { 
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* Since we'll have the "ul li" "float:left"
 * we need to add a clear after the container. */

nav:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}

/* Removing padding, margin and "list-style" from the "ul",
 * and adding "position:reltive" */
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

/* Positioning the navigation items inline */
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* Styling the links */
nav a {
    display:block;
    padding:14px 20px;  
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:17px;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height: 32px;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000000; }

/* Background color change on Hover */
nav a:hover { 
    background-color: #FFC213; 
}

/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    top: 60px; 
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:inherit;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
    width:170px;
    float:none;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

/* Second, Third and more Tiers 
 * We move the 2nd and 3rd etc tier dropdowns to the left
 * by the amount of the width of the first tier.
*/
nav ul ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    top:-60px;
    /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
    left:170px; 
}

/* Change ' +' in order to change the Dropdown symbol */
li > a:after { content:  ' +'; }
li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }

/* Media Queries
--------------------------------------------- */

@media all and (max-width : 768px) {
    nav {
        margin: 0;
    }

    /* Hide the navigation menu by default */
    /* Also hide the  */
    .toggle + a,
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Stylinf the toggle lable */
    .toggle {
        display: block;
        background-color: #000000;
        padding:14px 20px;  
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:17px;
        text-decoration:none;
        border:none;
    }

    .toggle:hover {
        background-color: #FFC213;
    }

    /* Display Dropdown when clicked on Parent Lable */
    [id^=drop]:checked + ul {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Change menu item's width to 100% */
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul ul .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        padding: 0 40px;
    }

    nav ul ul ul a {
        padding: 0 80px;
    }

    nav a:hover,
    nav ul ul ul a {
        background-color: #FFC213;
    }

    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a,
    nav ul ul ul a{
        padding:14px 20px;  
        color:#FFF;
        font-size:17px; 
    }

    nav ul li ul li .toggle,
    nav ul ul a {
        background-color: #212121; 
    }

    /* Hide Dropdowns by Default */
    nav ul ul {
        float: none;
        position:static;
        color: #ffffff;
        /* has to be the same number as the "line-height" of "nav a" */
    }

    /* Hide menus on hover */
    nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    /* Fisrt Tier Dropdown */
    nav ul ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul ul ul li {
        position: static;
        /* has to be the same number as the "width" of "nav ul ul li" */ 
    }
}

@media all and (max-width : 150px) {
    nav ul li {
        display:block;
        width: 94%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-last-child` selector. That will select the before last element, which is the first social icon. And give that `margin` or `padding` left to make a distance between them and the rest of the `li`

```css
nav ul li {
  float:left
}
nav ul {
  list-style:none
}
nav ul li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-left:50px
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>List Item</li>
  <li>social</li>
  <li>social</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```